# How to copy files to a destination with variable in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a destination for file copy as a variable `file_path`, how can I copy files to that destination using template/copy modules?

Tried:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: variable
    command: echo "emptyDir"
    register: file_path

  - name: check var value
    debug:
      var: file_path
      verbosity: 2

  - name: copy mod
    template:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "{{ file_path }}"
      mode: 0755
    with_items:
      - "file1.txt"
      - "file2.txt"
```

Error: 
If copy module is used
[copyModule error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFO8I.png)

If template module is used
[templateModule error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD3WR.png)

But throws some dict - string error.

Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Hi. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), more specifically the paragraph concerning code and errors in images. Edit your question to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Please share the value of `file_path` as well. I think the problem lies within the value you have used for `file_path`

Comment: If you just have to copy the files without having anything in the file which needs to be resolved like jinja2 template then use copy module, otherwise use template module.

Comment: @Shubham Vaishnav, Yes it worked with copy module itself but had to pass only stdout part of the variable. Else it is giving the entire output of variable which is a dictionary. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the issue could be with stdout, need to use file_path.stdout. Else it will be a dictionary.